# Import Opportunities using Data Loader in NPSP

Tags: data-loader, npsp, data-import

I need to import opportunity data to NPSP cloud.

Contact lookup to Account. And Opportunities lookup to both Account and Contact.

I first imported Contact data using data loader. And then imported Account data via data loader. And then mapped their ID's in the Opportunity excel sheet using VLookup.

(This is how I imported data while working in other clouds)

What I didn't realize was that while importing Contact data, it would automatically create a household account.

I now have duplicate account records in NPSP - the household account related to contact, and the account records imported(related to opportunity). The names of both account records are different - ContactLastName Household and OpportunityOrganization Name.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Which one (of the duplicate accounts) is the one you want or does it not matter?

Comment: NPSP has its own [data import tool](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/import-your-data-using-npsp-data-importer/discover-the-npsp-data-importer), which manages households and automatically connects objects. If applicable, it's recommended to use that tool to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I would like to keep OpportunityOrganization Name.

Comment: @DavidReed Thank you. Is it possible to import custom fields using the data import tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by following the following steps:

1. Delete OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts

   - Export the ID's of all Accounts.
   - Map the OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts with their corresponding ID using VLookup in excel.
   - Delete all OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts using data loader.
   - Keep the OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts names in the main table - they are mapped with contacts.(to be used later)
2. Map Account ID to Contact ID

   - Export the ID's of all Contacts
   - Map each contact with it's corresponding ID using VLookup in excel.
   - Map each contact ID with the corresponding Account ID it is looking up to.
   - This gives the ID's of all the ContactLastName Household accounts.
3. Upsert OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts

   - Each Account ID is a ContactLastName Household account.
   - Each Contact ID/Account ID has a corresponding OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts name.
   - Upsert the Account ID(of ContactLastName Household account) with the OpportunityOrganization Name Accounts name.
   - Now all the contacts are looking up to the correct account.